# Как выровнять текст в меню Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Разрабатываю программу на `Python` с помощью `Tkinter`. Столкнулся с проблемой при создании меню. Названия команд в пунктах меню, как правило, выглядят вот так:
[image: Эталон]

Т. е. названия "горячих клавиш" выровнены по правому краю.
Пытался сделать так же в своём проекте:

```
        self.menu = tk.Menu(self)
        self.config(menu=self.menu)
        self.file_menu = tk.Menu(self.menu, tearoff=0)
        self.file_menu.add_command(label='Открыть          CTRL+O', command=func_1)
        self.file_menu.add_command(label='Сохранить        CTRL+S', command=func_2)
```

Результат:
[image: В моём проекте]

Насколько я понимаю, это происходит из-за пропорционального шрифта. Есть ли способ решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для отображения строки в правой части, используется параметр `accelerator`

```
self.file_menu.add_command(label='Открыть', accelerator='CTRL+O', command=func_1)
self.file_menu.add_command(label='Сохранить', accelerator='CTRL+S', command=func_2)
```

Документация: https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/menus.html

Comment: Спасибо! Всё работает как надо.